# Getting data from cloud firestore using nodejs takes too long

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I am testing firebase with a NodeJs application and when I try to read data from a database that I have created with one collection it gets the data but it takes too much time to log the data on my terminal.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

let serviceAccount = require('./ServiceAccountKey.json');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://database url"
});

let db = admin.firestore();

db.collection('messages').get()
  .then((snapshot) => {
    snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
    });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('Error getting documents', err);
  });
```

[image]

I have also tried to write data on the database but I am always getting the following error when I try to do it using the below code:

```
let docRef = db.collection('test').doc('alovelace');

let setAda = docRef.set({
  first: 'Ada',
  last: 'Lovelace',
  born: 1815
}).then(function() {
  console.log('Data saved!');
}).catch(function(error) {
  console.log("Gor an error: ", error);
});
```

[image]

I would like to understand what I am doing wrong since I am reading 1 item only and trying to insert one item only. You support is really appreciated.

Comment: It's good practice when using `snapshot.forEach` to handle cases where there are no documents in that collection. This could be as simple as using `if (snapshot.empty) { throw 'expected documents' }` on the line above it.

Comment: I've spent some time trying to reproduce the problem to no avail. The code you have provided works without issue (responses within 1-2 seconds of starting node process) so there may be some problem with your network at play here. Sorry I can't help further than that.

Comment: @samthecodingman Thank you for the illustration and the effort to test my code. I was really confused since read approach was working but the writing approach was not. I thought that something wrong with the way I use firestore. I will try other connections and see if it is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

There may be some backdated dependencies. Try using

```
npm update
```